# Android Studio project cloned from Github only showing ReadMe

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

I'm trying to set up my Android project on my new laptop and I'm having some trouble. My project works fine on my PC, it's just the new setup I can't get working right. The project file is building properly, but it won't display in the project view. The files I can open show a red J in a circle. All attempts to update or pull just end in "All files up to date."

[image]

This is a link to my github profile: https://github.com/jschioppo/RecipeList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've not added project's `build.gradle` (located in project's root folder) to your github repo. Please add that to github and try importing again.

Answer (score 2):

I have downloaded this project and found that there are no project level build.gradle and settings.gradle files.

This is not an Android project it's a module. I am able to run this Module at my end. Do following steps:-

1. Create new Android project in your studio.
2. Once it is loaded. Goto File Menu and Click on Import new Module.
3. If you already have a Module named app then changed the Module name and import this Module.
4. Now you will be able to run this Application.

[image: You can see your project files in the screenshot here.]